# Getting DefaultCredentialsError even though environment has been set

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Inside my venv I have linked GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to "apikey.json" file.

And this command:

> os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]

Rightly gives

> 'apikey.JSON'

but on running my django application I still get the same error:

```
DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine 
credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or
explicitly create credential and re-run the application.
```

Is there anywhere else I need to pass my api json file?

Comment: Where exactly are you running your django application?, please take into consideration that the credentials will only work on the test environment.

If you are deploying an application, it will be necessary to include them into the app.yaml file. Or if you are using it from a VM, you might need load the permission from your code directly.

Comment: @Ggrimaldo running locally.